# How do I execute a .c file?

Tags: c

I have a `.c` file with a program (obviously written in C):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I'm having problems running it.

At first, this happened:

```
$ ./file.c
bash: ./file.c: Permission denied
```

I then added execute permissions with `chmod +x file.c`, but it still didn't work:

```
$ ./file.c
./file.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./file.c: line 3: `int main(int argc, char** argv) {'
```

However, as far as I know, this C program should be syntactically correct.

How do I execute it?

Comment: That's usually easier. But the C code has to be compiled and linked to give an executable. Or you need a C interpreter...

Comment: *Your post doesn't have a question.* What did you try? Did you get an error message? What is the actual problem we are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot execute an file ".c" from shell. You must compile it first.

For example:
We have an file called "file.c"

1. Open a terminal
2. Use gcc for compile the file and make an executable (`gcc file.c -o executable`)
3. Now you can open the executable file since shell (just go to the folder and execute `./executable`